# How to take more than 1 element off a list and keep it as a tuple, and then assign the tuple as the key of a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Say there is a list of strings. I want to take n number of strings from the list and store it as a tuple. Then I would like to make a dictionary where the recently created tuple is the key. What's the fast way of doing this?

Comment: Provide sample data, expected output and also show us what have you tried

Comment: Is there a non-fast way that you tried?

Comment: can you provide an example of what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new dictionary:

```
dic = dict()
```

Create a list:

```
list = ["banana","apple","orange","watermelon"]
```

Assign a tuple to the key of dict:

```
dic[(list[0],list[1])] = 3
```

Then you can print the result:

```
print(dic[("banana","apple")])
3
```